# What is the error in this case...when statement?

Tags: cognos, cognos-8, cognos-bi

Could anyone say what is the wrong with the below statement.

Currently I'm working in cognos 10.1.1

```
case     
  when extract(month,_last_of_month (current_date))=1 then ('January')
  when extract(month,_last_of_month (current_date))=2 then ('January','February')  
end
```

I couldn't correct it.

The error code is ***qe-def-0459 cclexception parsing error***

Comment: @JW, qe-def-0459 cclexception parsing error

Comment: If I'm understanding your logic correctly, I think you mean to return only `February` in the second case, not both `January` and `February`, right?  That gives an error, coz it's supposed to return just one value per `THEN`.

Comment: what is this `_last_of_month`?

Comment: @JW **_last_of_month** is a cognos built-in function.

Comment: @BeemerGuy.net If the second case is true, I wanna return both **January** and **February**.

Answer (score 1):

it should return only one value,

```
case
   when extract(month,_last_of_month(current_date)) = 1 then 'January'
   when extract(month,_last_of_month(current_date)) = 2 then 'January, February'
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot JW, but I'd like to have FEBRUARY in a separate line. Could you help?

Comment: @WKordos I'm using it in cognos. It is like a condition.

Answer (score 1):

I also believe in all Case Statements in Cognos you must have an else condition as well.  I don't have cognos in front of me and cant remember the syntax of the functions you are using but it looks good.

Also i remember in some versions of cognos you had to convert the eval expression  to the same as the return type meaning since you are returning text instead of expr = 1 you would have to Cast(expre, varchar) = Cast(1, varchar) ---  Not sure if this is the case in 10 but it definitely caused problems sometimes as recently as 8.3 and 8.4